# Bootstrap 3 multi input-group-addon style behavior

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap3 and I would like to use multiple inputs-group-addon together.
If I try to do so, unfortunately I get in some elements a 2px border instead of 1px.
[image]

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/oKHvtOhDcb)

What kind of CSS style I could use to solve my problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following CSS:

```
.input-group-addon{
     border-left: 0;
}
```

This will work. See **[this](http://www.bootply.com/cRe3LpvX7X)**.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common known problem in bootstrap, you can overcome this problem by overriding '.inputs-group-addon' class.

[bootply](http://www.bootply.com/1UY0gL9Vq4)

**Example**

```
.input-group-addon:first-child + .input-group-addon:last-child {
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.input-group-addon:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) + .input-group-addon:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
    border-left: 0;
}

.form-control + .input-group-addon:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
    border-left: 0;
}

.input-group-addon:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) + .form-control {
    border-left: 0;
}
```

Also there is an [issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9025) in bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks, but the solution of Rahul Pratap Singh seems to be simpler

Comment: I used a variation of this solution and it worked better than the accepted answer.